# Developers should be able to review companies in Jobs

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

[image]
Developers are first if and only if developers are given an avenue to rate a company based on past experience.  Right now company pages do not allow you, the developer, to provide your current or prior feedback like Glassdoor does.  It hides a lot of information from potential developers who are looking for work but don't know the truth behind company X.

Also what does fake job listings mean?  I found one years ago prying about developers trying to take work from a contract type position where my work was being split up by two different companies.

Comment: I stand by my post whether you agree or don't agree - that is what Meta is for.  Developers not being able to review a company is not a developer first website.

Comment: A fake job listing is a bait-and-switch strategy used to add resumes to a database. Basically, a company posts a role that isn't actually an available position - it's just a way to draw applicants and grow the database. It's a common concern for job seekers we've spoken to.

Comment: And donna you stop paying customers from doing that?  Sorry I dont believe it Ive found these issues on this site.

Comment: i mean... there's always the contact us form if you find a particular listing that's problematic or fraudulent. Allowing people to rate a company and displaying that rating publicly is more likely to result in companies being rated negatively due to reasons unrelated to what the rating is for (for example, getting a negative for rejecting an applicant that wasn't qualified.) Since all voting is anonymous, the rating wouldn't really mean a whole lot. All it would do is give you, a potentially annoyed person, an action to take that would alleviate said annoyance, even if only temporarily.

Comment: out of space; i didn't actually mean *you* specifically, but, the dev that would have cast a vote.

Comment: @Donna It is a common concern. How does Stack Overflow prevent it though? I put in an application in December for a company, had a conversation with HR and then was told that they don't have a budget for the position. That seems pretty bait and switchy to me, yet the job was posted here. I chalked it up to a learning experience and have ignored the company the couple times I've seen a job posted by them again.

Comment: @Andy the answer is they cannot even if they wanted to.

Comment: *ye who offereth the cabbage shall rule over them all...*

Comment: @andy thanks for letting us know. Re: how we prevent it, users and staff report inappropriate job listings, which are then passed thru our support team. If the listing doesn't abide by our policy, the company will need to fix the listing. That said, your story brought up internal discussion about (1) clarifying our policy and (2) getting the right reporting features in place so that if something like your case happens, it's easy for you to let us know. Thanks again for the feedback.

Comment: @Donna and you will get rid of the highlighted message because its false correct?

Comment: What is the status of this ticket?

Answer (score -1):

Including the developer's voice in a job listing in some way seems helpful.

To avoid gaming the system: As an idea on how to **limit reviews**: this could be a privilege awarded with tag badges.

If a company lists several badges for its job listing, owners of at least the bronze tag badge could be allowed to vote. This would add actual utility to the badges, while reducing abuse potential by only allowing answers/votes/... by persons with high domain knowledge.

Comment: But domain knowledge in a tag doesn't mean that they have any knowledge of the company.

Comment: @BSMP: if you have more accurate ways to restrict it, feel welcome. You could of course additionally restrict it to applicants etc, but without some restrictive limits, the abuse potential seems significant.

Comment: This could even be more accurate. Given that SO jobs knows who I applied for and in fact knows I have been Accepted by Company X the "review" could be as simple as being enabled based on this criteria alone. Yes you will get much less reviews, yes you may get one or two where the candidate was Accepted but never joined the job but this is minor to me. The system would simply allow this candidate who meets this criteria to submit a review. System would be more trust worthy and people could actually count on it - making it developers FIRST now. As it stands Companies are first.